# Segfault when attempting to free malloc'd memory (and pointers)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

I am having trouble trying to free a malloc'd block of memory. 
Basically I'm trying to create an array of strings, as so:

```
    char **list;
    list = malloc(total_num_elements * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0; i < total_num_elements; i++) {
        list[i] = malloc((str_len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    }
```

and then send it to a recursive function that generates permutations of a string (the first parameter), using the following function call and the prototype:

```
    recurse(str, 0, str_len, &list);
    recurse(char *str, int start, int end, char ***list);
```

The pertinent snippet of the recursive function is the base case:

```
    if (start == end) {
        strcpy((*list)[counter], str);
        counter++;
    }
```

counter is just some global variable I was using for convenience. As you can probably tell I'm trying to store the permutations into list.

When I try to free everything at the end of the program by doing

```
    for (i = 0; i < total_num_elements; i++) {
        free(list[i]);
    }
    free(list);
```

everything's fine and dandy, but as soon as I call the function that declares and allocates list again the whole thing blows up. Getting rid of the free() statements got rid of the segfault, but I got plainly gibberish results stored in list.

What am I missing? I tried manually copying the contents of str into list with a for loop and the error persists (as expected). All strings are null-terminated.

Comment: So what you're saying is you're malloc-ing inside a function? It may have something to do with local variables and you may be free-ing something that's not there. You're calling the allocation and the free function multiple times?

Comment: The malloc and free calls all occur within the same function (I'll just call it function alpha). I'll look at it again for the local variables issue, but I pored over that function and didn't see anything that stuck out.

What I posted above are the only times I malloc that space and free it. The free() call is the very last thing in the function. I meant that I call function alpha multiple times from main().

Comment: Trying to understand what you're trying to do. You're calling your alpha function for different input strings so you can store your permutations into the list? Could you give an example of how you use your alpha function?

Comment: Sorry bout that. Function alpha is pretty much the main driver function for what I'm trying to do. It takes a single input string (like "0123" or "Hello") and sends it (once) to a recursive function, which generates all permutations of that string. I'm trying to store these permutations in list as they're generated, so I can use them later in function alpha.

After I'm done using them (so at the end of function alpha) I try to free everything, which is when it fails.

Comment: And you say that if you get rid of the free section you get unreadable results? What is it you're printing?